# Displaying tf.summary.text with underscores correctly in Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, markdown, tensorboard

I want to log a few strings with underscores to tensorboard. However, the underscores are treated as emphasis somewhere in the pipeline. Here's some example code to illustrate the problem. I've included a few versions that attempt to escape the underscores

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
text0 = """/a/b/c_d/f_g_h_2017"""
text1 = """/a/b/c\_d/f\_g\_h\_2017"""
text2 = """/a/b/c\\_d/f\\_g\\_h\\_2017"""

summary_op0 = tf.summary.text('text', tf.convert_to_tensor(text0))
summary_op1 = tf.summary.text('text', tf.convert_to_tensor(text1))
summary_op2 = tf.summary.text('text', tf.convert_to_tensor(text2))
summary_op = tf.summary.merge([summary_op0, summary_op1, summary_op2])
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/tensorboard', sess.graph)
summary = sess.run(summary_op)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary, 0)
summary_writer.flush()
summary_writer.close()
```

Here's the output:

[image]

How can I use tensorboard to properly render strings with tensorboard?
Package versions: Tensorflow 1.3.0, TensorBoard 0.1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this github issue, this is a bug with the current tensorsorboard and Python 3. For now, using backticks as suggested in another answer is sufficient to render the underscores correctly.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/647#issuecomment-337380296

Comment: The bug should be fixed with the next release, as of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/commit/0e05e140439527d10df65c73702878a2b726f2e0

Answer (score 2):

This is working as intended. The docs [for `tf.summary.text`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/text) and also [for `tensorboard.summary.text`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/9a9fab1e8e285469e4f598fb11780134208d156e/tensorboard/plugins/text/summary.py#L36-L37) state that the text will be rendered using Markdown formatting—just like the text in this question and answer—and in Markdown, underscores create *italics.*

If you don't want this to be the case, you can consider formatting these strings as code, by using either

```
text0 = """`/a/b/c_d/f_g_h_2017`"""  # backticks: inline code formatting
text1 = """    /a/b/c\_d/f\_g\_h\_2017"""  # four-space indent: code block
```

This yields the following result:

[image: Screenshot of the resulting text dashboard]

(Disclaimer: I work on TensorBoard.)

Comment: thanks, I did note the documentation. Several searches led me to believe that I could escape underscores with backslashes... clearly I found the wrong resources